# node.js seg fault with no errors being reported on stdout

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-11.04

Running on Ubuntu 11.04

We have a node.js server that is crashing about once per day without warning. The following shows up in the syslog:

```
eb  7 16:11:09  kernel: [14840854.810206] node[24380]: segfault at     ffffffffffffffff ip 000000000062a938 sp 00007fff3ccdf9f0 error 4 in node[400000+5ab000]
```

Nothing shows up in our logs or on stdout from the node.js server. Note that we have two other node.js servers running on the same server and neither one of them have experienced this problem.

Also, we are monitoring memory usage and the offending server was at an acceptable memory level (~800Mb) at the time of the crash.

Comment: how to you installed node.js? which version of node.js is installed?

Comment: 0.4.9, installed from source cloned from github some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

There's been quite a few segfault fixes since 0.4.9. Search through [the changelog](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html) for "segfault" to see the specifics.

Updating to a more recent version of node would likely fix this bug.

I realize this question was posted 2 years ago, but it's this far unanswered.